# Создать promise через new Function

Tags: javascript, typescript

есть следующий код

```
const  f = new Function('return new Promise(resolve,reject){ resolve(\'hi\')};');
      f.prototype.then(title => this.title = title);
```

надо создать промис через new Function. Выдает ошибку, что делать

Comment: Зачем именно через new Function, и почему вы думали, что этот код должен работать?

Comment: я передаю функцию через  postMessage дочерний  iframe,  его надо там запустить

Comment: _я передаю функцию через postMessage_ - об этом надо писать в вопросе: от этого зависит ответ. Для кода в вопросе достаточно сразу вызвать полученную функцию `f = new Function(...)()`, а дальше добавить then напрямую в `f` а не прототип. Но судя по всему то, что хочешь сделать ты - невозможно реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код

```
const  f = new Function('', 'return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ resolve(\'hi\');})')();
f.then(title => this.title = title);
```

Comment: а почему пустые кавычки вначале?

Comment: @ШерзодЁров в первом аргументе конструктора Function перечисляются аргументы принимаемые новой функцией. Например, `f = new Function('a, b', 'return a+b')(1, 2);`

Comment: @ШерзодЁров. _а почему пустые кавычки вначале?_ - потому что это список параметров, его можно опустить, если он пустой